# Why will some segue to display a sheet work fine and another in the same storyboard show the sheet and not execute and code

Tags: swift, macos, segue

I have a macOS app that seques to a bunch of view controllers.  some work and some do not.
I have buttons that the triggered segues go directly to the next view controller.
I have buttons that the sent actions go thru code to segue as

```
@IBAction func sequeToThree(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "sequeToThree", sender: nil)
}
```

All the segues are defined as Sheet segue "segueTo a controller" to "controller name"

the view controller is always displayed, but some execute code and some do not.
I have verified that all the seque to controllers are the same.
I deleted one controller and seque and re added it, and it worked correctly.
I added a new controller and seque doing the same thing, and it only displayed the sheet, no code was executed.
even though the code does not execute, one controller for testing is set with a button that has the "Sent Actions" as view name dismissController: , and that works, and a button that is connected to a `@IBAction`, and that does not work.

using Xcode Version 12.3

I do not know what else to check!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should never post your full code to an external repo, but rather include all relevant code in the question itself, in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the missing click of the Module under the Custom Class of the view controller in the storyboard.

Setting it to the name of the app solved the problem.

Lesson learned, create a custom class, you have to have a module to supply it